# Multiple values from same txt file

Tags: testing, groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I've been using this script to load values separated by new line from files to send requests with different values.

```
def size 
File valueFile = new File("C:\\values\\myValueFile.txt")
File valueFile2 = new File("C:\\values\\myValueFile2.txt")
List lines = valueFile.readLines()
List lines2 = valueFile2.readLines()
size = lines.size.toInteger()
def myProps = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties") 

for( counter in 0..size-1) 
{
tempValue = lines[counter]
tempValue2 = lines2[counter]
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value", tempValue)
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value2", tempValue2)
log.info tempValue
log.info tempValue2
testRunner.runTestStepByName("updateBusinessTrip")
}
```

How to make it load values from same file separated by ";"?
txt file would look like that:

```
Value1;Value2
Value1.1;Value2.1
Value1.2;Value2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you...:

Option 1:

```
tempValue = lines[counter].split(/;/)
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value", tempValues[0])
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value2", tempValue[1])
```

or Option 2:

```
(tempValue, tempValue2) = lines[counter].tokenize(';')
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value", tempValues)
myProps.setPropertyValue("Value2", tempValue2)
```

or another one:

```
File valueFile = new File("C:\\values\\myValueFile.txt")
def myProps = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties") 
valueFile.splitEachLine(/;/) { items ->
    myProps.setPropertyValue("Value", items[0])
    myProps.setPropertyValue("Value2", items[1])
    log.info tempValue
    log.info tempValue2
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("updateBusinessTrip")
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I needed :)